# Vue Js - Loop via v-for X times (in a range)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

How can I repeat a loop via `v-for` X (e.g. 10) times?

```html
<!-- want to repeat this (e.g.) 10 times -->

<ul>
  <li v-for="item in shoppingItems">
    {{ item.name }} - {{ item.price }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The documentation shows:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in 10">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>

<!-- or -->

<li v-for="n in 10">{{ n }} </li>

<!-- this doesn't work -->

<li v-for="item in 10">{{ item.price }}</li>
```

but from where does vue know the source of the objects?
If I render it like the doc says, I get the number of items and items, but without content.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just iterate shoppingItems?

Comment: Hy Bert - I only want to know how to give a v-for (the simplest way) a (x) number of repeats and the example in the doc do not work...... .... in pure js + ajax its so simple return < 9 or or or, but this dont work in the method...

Comment: There are two distinct modes to `v-for`; when it is called against an integer, and when it is called against an array. Mixing those modes and trying to use an integer to control access to content of an array is likely to cause problems. If you need a subset of the array you can filter it.

Comment: You MUST to iterate what you desire to show, if shoppingItems collection doesnt fit to you because of their length (because I'm assuming that as the problem) but it fits you because of their content, you MUST then to create a computed property returning a new array slicing the original array with your desired length...and then iterate that computed array, I find this is the proper way to do it

Answer (score 392):

You can use an index in a range and then access the array via its index:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="index in 10" :key="index">
    {{ shoppingItems[index].name }} - {{ shoppingItems[index].price }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that this is 1-indexed: in the first iteration, `index` is 1, and in the second iteration, `index` is 2, and so forth.

You can also check the [Official Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) for more information.

Comment: It works ::) I have changed it slightly to <li v-for="(n,index) in 2">{{ shoppingItems.price }}</li> ====  MNY THXXXX Coder*****! ====

Comment: How to make that 10 a variable?, form the data of the component?

Comment: Why this is 1-indexed is completely beyond me. `<span v-for="i in 5">{{i}} </span>` => `1 2 3 4 5`. Use `<span v-for="(e, i) in 5">{{i}} </span>` to get 0-indexing.

Comment: I noticed that you should write shoppingItems[index -1].name to iterate over entire array

Comment: @ggorlen the `v-for` directive is different from the standard JS for loop. The first argument is an alias for the array element (not the index) in the standard use case. The index is given as a second element so `(e, i)` returns the element and its index. When using `v-for="n in 10"`, `n` is the "element" which, I guess, is index+1. So you're solution is correct: to get the index use `v-for="(n, i) in 10"` where `n` is 1-indexed and `i` is 0-indexed. Details about the directive are at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Small note but here, `index` is the actual element and not an index. If that would be the case, using a (real) index would be a quite bad practice overall.

Answer (score 73):

I have solved it with Dov Benjamin's help like that:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="(n,index) in 2">{{ n }}, {{ index }}</li>
</ul>
```

Note that in this case, `n` is 1-indexed, and `index` is 0-indexed.

And another method, for both V1.x and 2.x of vue.js

```
Vue 1:

<p v-for="item in items | limitBy 10">{{ item }}</p>

Vue2:

// Via slice method in computed prop

<p v-for="item in filteredItems">{{ item }}</p>

computed: {
   filteredItems: function () {
     return this.items.slice(0, 10)
     }
  }
```

Comment: I had to add `:key` to get it to work in vue3 thus `<li v-for="(n, index) in 2" :key="index">{{ n }}, {{ index }}</li>`

Comment: @abulka the key was already highly suggested when looping. But yeah, I confirm that it works pretty much the same way with Vue3.

Comment: PS: you're using `item in items | limitBy 10` here, a good thing to know is that filters (used with `|`) does not exist anymore in Vue3: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html Thought it would be nice to know why that one would maybe not work at some point.

Answer (score 37):

I had to add `parseInt()` to tell v-for it was looking at a number.

```html
<li v-for="n in parseInt(count)" :key="n">{{n}}</li>
```

Comment: Note that this is 1-indexed.

Comment: Thank you! This worked in vue 2.6.12 !

Comment: This did the trick when I tried using variables for the count. Thanks!

Comment: That should be needed only if `count` is a string.

Answer (score 30):

You can use the native JS slice method:

```html
<div v-for="item in shoppingItems.slice(0,10)">
```

> The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

Based on tip in the migration guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-limitBy-Filter

Answer (score 26):

**SOLUTION 1:**

```html
<p v-for="i in 5" :key="i">{{ i }}</p>
```

Remember, result will be from 1-5.

[image]

**SOLUTION 2:**
If you want to show limited number of elements in array. You should use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method of JavaScript.

```html
<p v-for="i in usersList.slice(0,5)" :key="i">{{ i }}</p>
```

Comment: This starts at `1` though, not `0`....

Comment: Yes @DouglasGaskell you are right. 
Result will be = 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: usersList.slice(0,5) would be preferred to return via computed and not use it directly in template like this.

Answer (score 6):

The same goes for  v-for in **range**:

```html
<li v-for="n in 20 " :key="n">{{n}}</li>
```

Comment: Please check [tdhulster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931666/tdhulster) answer first.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can solve,

**First One is,**

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in items.slice(0,10)" :key="index">
```

**Second one is,**

```html
<li v-for="item  in 20 " :key="item">{{item}}</li>
```

Hope you get your answer, thank you.

Comment: Can you explain how they can solve, and what are the condition to choose the second instead of the first ? Please [edit] your answer :)

Comment: @Elikill58, Heyy, It means, v-fop loop will be continued 20(X number) times.
FYI, 20 is not fixed number, its X times.

Comment: Not a good practice to use the index as a key.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to loop x number of times you can simply use the following:

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in 10" :key="index">{{ item }}</div>
```

Comment: this is the same answer as above

Comment: Not a good practice to use the index as a key.

Comment: @kissu: what? why? this is how all the examples everywhere told me to do. Why do you think it would be wrong to use the index as a key?

Comment: @Fred usually, examples are sloppy, and don't really care about that part. Google for that, and you'll see that it's a bad practice to use the index since the index can mutate (if you're removing an element in your array for example), hence defeats the purpose of having something unique.

Answer (score 2):

try a v-if in the v-for, so for example if you want to only show less than 3 (o r any arbitrary amount) in items, then you can do something like this.

```
<span v-for="(item, itemIndex) in items" :key="itemIndex">
  <div v-if="itemIndex < 3">
   <p>

   {{ item }}

  </p>
 </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a **key** is now **required**.

```html
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
```

[Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/261)

Comment: It was always a nice thing to have already, glad that it's required now.

Answer (score 0):

First Version

```
// I expect your data like this
shoppingItems: [
  {
    name: "Clothes A",
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    name: "Clothes B",
    price: 5000
  },
  {
    name: "Clothes C",
    price: 20000
  }
]

<ul>
  // The item in here means each object in shoppingItems
  <li v-for="item in shoppingItems"> 
    {{ item.name }} - {{ item.price }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example code above is for loop each item in shoppingItems

Second Version

```
<ul>
  // The index will start form 0 until 10 - 1
  <li v-for="index in 10"> 
    {{ shoppingitems[index].name }} - {{ shoppingitems[index].price }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul v-for="(item, index) in items.slice(0,10)" :key="item.index">
<li>
 {{item.name}}-{{item.price}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me..

```
<li v-for="(index,key) in data.slice(0,5)" :key="key">{{ index.title }}</li>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you should use index of array like this:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="index in 10">
    {{ shoppingItems[index].name }} - {{ shoppingItems[index].price }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

You must be careful if the shoppingItems has 2 objects, the result is undefind for index 3, 4, ...

It is better to use shoppingItems.length instead of 10

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need a step of something different than 1:

```
<select>
    <option v-for="i in 55/5" :key="i">{{ i*5 }}</option>
</select>
```

Will result on a select with options from 0 to 55 with a step of 5.