# V for loop incremental

Tags: vue.js

```
<table style="cursor:default">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="j in status_data.length/2">
                            <td class="w3-border w3-border-black w3-round-large w3-center" :bgcolor="getColor(status_data[j-1].MESSAGE_CODE)">{{ status_data[j-1].PROCESS_CODE }}</td>
                            <td class="w3-border w3-border-black w3-round-large w3-center" :bgcolor="getColor(status_data[j].MESSAGE_CODE)">{{ status_data[j].PROCESS_CODE }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

how can i control value of j in above code , i want it is like

for i in status_data.length/2
do action 
i=i+2

i want to increment value by 2 in every iteration .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Only use every second index in the array? Can you provide more information so we can help you find a solution?

Comment: i have jason objects , total elements are 12 .

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 , i want in my first iteration 1,2 , in second iteration 3,4 , in third iteration 5,6 so on

Comment: I think this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617484/vue-js-loop-via-v-for-x-times-in-a-range

Answer (score 0):

If you want it by pairs, go through the array and collect pairs whenever the index is an even number.

```
status_data
.map((v, i) => i%2 === 0 ? arr.slice(i, i+2) : [])
.filter(x => x.length > 0)
```

```
console> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
.map((v, i) => i%2 === 0 ? arr.slice(i, i+2) : [])
.filter(x => x.length > 0)

// will return an array like [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
```

Beware that this will ignore the last element if your array has an odd number of elements