# The v-for range expect an integer value but got NaN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

v-for directive is unable to read `nStars` prop to execute loop. Look I'm trying to display multiple stars by using the component `<display-stars>`. But for some reason the component is not receiving the `nStars` prop to execute loop. This is my code:
**HTML**

```
<h1><display-stars :nStars="3"></display-stars></h1>
```

**Logic**

```
  const app = Vue.createApp({}); // It contains more logic, but it's not relevant.
  app.component("star", { template: `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>` });
  app.component("empty-star", { template: `<i class="far fa-star"></i>` });
  app.component("display-stars", {
    props: ["nStars"],
    template: `<div class="stars-container">
     <star v-for="i in nStars" :key="i"></star> <empty-star v-for="j in (5-nStars)" :key="j"></empty-star>
    </div>`,
  });

  const componentInstance_vm = app.mount("#app");
```

I tried reading the vue docs about [how to pass props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#passing-static-or-dynamic-props), and [how to use v-for using an integer instead of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871839/14495889). I might forgot something since I'm really new to **Vue 3**, but come from a react background.

Comment: I would think the trouble comes from your keyIndex. Try ```v-for="(i, index) in nStars" :key="index"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nStars` is a `Number`. You can use `v-for` [only with arrays or objects](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#mapping-an-array-to-elements-with-v-for).

To create an `Array` of 3 elements you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) :

```
let arr = Array.from({length: 3});
```

which will create `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.
(You can create arrays with non-undefined elements too. Refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).)

So to loop `nStars` times in Vue do :

```
<star v-for="(o,i) in Array.from({length: nStars})" :key="i"></star>
```

where `i` is the index.